# How to add a insert no/yes for break or continue

Tags: python

Answers.py

```
import Multiplications
import Start



def finish(choice, num1, num2):

 if choice == "1": 
    print(num1, "+", num2, "=", Multiplications.Add(num1, num2))

 elif choice == "2": 
    print(num1, "-", num2, "=", Multiplications.Subtract(num1, num2))

 elif choice == "3": 
    print(num1, "*", num2, "=", Multiplications.Multiply(num1, num2)) 

 elif choice == "4": 
    print(num1, "/", num2, "=", Multiplications.Divide(num1, num2))
```

Main.py

```
import nd
import Answers
import Multiplications
import Start

Start.operations()
nd.operation()
```

Multiplications.py

```
#This function adds two numbers
def Add(x, y):
    return x + y

#This function subtracts two numbers
def Subtract(x, y):
    return x - y

#This function multiplies two numbers
def Multiply(x, y):
    return x * y

#This function divides two numbers
def Divide(x, y):
    return x / y
```

nd.py

```
import Answers

def operation():   
  choice = input("Choose 1, 2, 3, or 4: ")
  #Check if the input is one of the four options
  if choice in ("1", "2", "3", "4"):
    num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
    num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))
    Answers.finish(choice, num1, num2)
```

Start.py

```
def operations():
 import time
 print("Select Operation: ")
 #time.sleep(1)
 print("1) Add")
 #time.sleep(1)
 print("2) Subtract")
 #time.sleep(1)
 print("3) Multiply")
 #time.sleep(1)
 print("4) Divide")
```

I want to add a command where after the answer is given from the given num1 and num2 i want a insert line to appear asking Would you like to do our next multiplication (Yes/No):

I think i should make another def but it didnt work, can somebody help. Thanks!

Comment: I think you are using a bit too many functions for such a simple program. For example all the addition, subtraction, multiplication and division code is in my opinion not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `while True` loop to play infinitly, then

- add another input to continue or not

  ```py
  def operation():
      while True:
          choice = input("Choose 1, 2, 3 or 4: ")
          if choice in "1234":
              num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
              num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))
              Answers.finish(choice, num1, num2)

          stop = input("Do you want to stop (yes)/no ?")
          if stop == "no":
              break
  ```
- use a fifth option that stop the game

  ```py
  def operation():
      while True:
          choice = input("Choose 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5: ")
          if choice in "1234":
              num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
              num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))
              Answers.finish(choice, num1, num2)

          elif choice == '5':
              break
  ```

Answer (score 0):

For the program to run in repeat, the simplest way to do so is to use a `While True` loop

```
import Answers
    
def operation():
    while True:   

        choice = input("Choose 1, 2, 3, or 4, or stop ")
        #Check if the input is one of the four options
        if choice in ("1", "2", "3", "4"):
            num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
            num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))
        Answers.finish(choice, num1, num2)
        if choice == "stop":
            sure_to_stop = input("are you sure you want to stop? Y/N)
        if sure_to_stop.lower() == "y':
            break
```